# how to zoom an image within the frame

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

In my web page I've tired to make a grid type image gallery.I want on hover image should be zoomed within the frame.( Example: http://cad180.com/About )[on hover images are zoomed within the frame].

```css
.gal {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.gal img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .gal {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="gal">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me doing this also the middle portion and right portion images are not zooming properly .Help me please .[MY DEMO CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/tanmndz/kLbzg6fx/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you need wrap your `img` element with a `div` and do `overflow: hidden` on it:

```
.grid {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLbzg6fx/2/)**

for your second problem you need to use `backface-visibility: hidden;` to fix it. read more about it **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)**.

Comment: thanks for that,But the right side and middle side is not working properly on hover

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your images in containers and add `overflow: hidden;` to the containers.

Also remove the padding from the `img` elements and style the spacing on the containers.

```css
.gal {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
  display: block;
}

.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 14px 0;
}

.zoom {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.gal img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .gal {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="gal">
        <li class="image-container">
          <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
          <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
          <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
          <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
          <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
          <img class="zoom" src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: loom at the right side and middle portion images..They are not showing properly at the time of zoom